# replace url into anchor tag with using nl2br in laravel blade

Tags: javascript, php, html, regex, laravel

hello i have laravel blade and here is the part that have the issue

```
@php
$reg_exUrl = "/(http|https|ftp|ftps)\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(\/\S*)?/";
@endphp

<div class="message"> 
                        @php
$text = nl2br(e($message));
@endphp
@if(preg_match($reg_exUrl, $text, $url)){!! preg_replace($reg_exUrl, '<a href="$0" target="_blank">$0</a> ', $text) !!}
@else {!!$text!!}
@endif
</div>
```

this works good if the link is only in the text but if it got mixed with some words and some break line
like this message

> hello dear buyer
>
> the link is working good https://google.com/blabla
>
> and some random text

it converted to this html code

```html
hello dear buyer<br>
<br>
the link is working good<br>
<a href="https://google.com/blabla<br" target="_blank">https://google.com/blabla<br< a="">  /&gt;
<br>
and some random text<br>
<br>
```

how to fix this

i want to replace the url into anchor tag and show the break line if the user enters message contains lines

also to use the e() function in blade to prevent any html code from running

any one help please

Comment: What is the content of `$message`
If you want to remove the html tags from your $message you can do this:
`$text = nl2br(e(strip_tags($message)));`

Comment: the content of the $message is in the question "hello dear buyer.... "and i already do nl2br and e() function my question is for how to add the link to anchor with nl2br

Comment: `nl2br` must be run after the regex replaement, `$text = nl2br(preg_replace($reg_exUrl, '<a href="$0" target="_blank">$0</a> ', $message));`, see https://3v4l.org/qKkpR

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, your code just works if there is only a space before the `<br>` tag. I don't think you can do this since the 
 is tied to link. Maybe you can do this for now (until someone else has a better solution) and make sure the `e()` is called after the str_replace:

```
$message = str_replace('<br>', ' <br>', $message);

// Optional to trim double spaces
$message = preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', $message);
```